# Regular expressions :buffer same characters

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep

I want to search in a text with regular expressions 3 same characters. For Example (111, ***,!!!, 999)

What I tried:

**first try**: `(\w{3})|(\d{3})\1`

**second try**: `[\w+]{3}|[\d+]{3}\1`

Comment: What tool do you want to use? `linux` is not a regex tool itself.

Comment: what do you mean with ''tool''? the only i want is to search 3same characters in a text :)

Comment: Should the characters be consecutive? The question still remains what tool you will use to handle the regex: `grep`? `sed`? `awk`?

Comment: grep needs. .Sed and awk what are the difference between grep?

Comment: there are many differences in which modes are supported, etc. I've written an answer that uses `grep`.

Comment: thanks:) i test it ,worked fine but i couldnt tick it fast (needs 2 minutes thats why i late to tick ) :)

Comment: `grep` is to **G**lobally find a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint text containing the string that matches it. `sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor for simple substitutions on individual lines (it has constructs to do more than that but they became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, people use them today just for the mental exercise not for production code). `awk` is a general purpose text manipulation tool so it is for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grep`, you can enable the *extended mode* option `-E` which will enable back-referencing and use the following regex:

```
grep -E '(.)\1\1' < file
```

It will emit all lines contain three consecutive equal characters. For instance if the file is:

```
aaa
aab
bab
bbb
aaccca
asdad
!!!
999
```

It will result in:

```
$ grep -E '(.)\1\1' < testin2
aaa
bbb
aaccca
!!!
999
```

The regex works as follows: the dot (`.`) matches every character (not taking new lines into account though). Now since we put it between brackets `(.)` can be references using a backreference group. Next we write two consecutive `\1`s such that the regex is looking for the pattern matched by the dot - one character thus - to be repeated an additional two times with no other characters in between.

If you **only** want to emit the three consecutive characters, you can pass `grep` the `-o` parameter:

```
$ grep -P '(.)\1\1' < testin2
aaa
bbb
aaccca
!!!
999
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash shell, you can use:

```
egrep 'aaa'
egrep '111'
```

and so on

If you are using a programming language like Java you can use something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The \\1 is used to match to the last selected group and so using it consecutively you can match as many characters as desired.

Comment: The extended mode of `grep` allows backreferences as well.